# What is a self-propelling "working" piston mechanism called?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

In anticipation of the Redstone Update, I've been experimenting with this type of "wormhead" piston configuration lately:

[image: "Wormhead configuration"]

or:

```
PSXXXXSP
```

where P = normal piston, S = sticky piston, X = anything .

By alternating power to the two pistons at the extremes, one can move the entire chain in the given direction. A usage of example would be a cane farm like this one:

[image: farm 1] [image: farm 2]

or an extendable fence.

This type of configuration will become more useful with the next update (hoppers allow continuous collection of items, redstone blocks allow easier movement in two dimensions).

I don't recall this type of mechanism described anywhere I read (including the Wiki), but as this is **basically an extension of the self-propelling piston concept**, I doubt that there isn't already a name for it. So, **what is the popular name of this type of contraption**?

Comment: God i wish I was this creative with redstone. You guys come up with so much awesome stuff.

Comment: Well, in fairness, I have an engineering background, and I suspect a lot of people who do the more complex stuff have one as well, so I wouldn't say this has necessarily anything to do with your "creativity", and you could probably quickly get up to speed by reading a bit about, say, computer logic :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an inchworm drive. [The name is typically used in connection with RedPower frame/motor contraptions](https://www.google.ca/search?q=inchworm+drive), but it's not a actual block's name so it's not especially tied to the RedPower way of building one. It's not unlike what is called an [inchworm motor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inchworm_motor) in the real world, so it's a pretty reasonable name for it in the first place. RedPower's users have invented a precedent for calling machines like that in Minecraft "inchworm drives", so using it to describe the same thing implemented with different blocks seems reasonable too.

Comment: That looks excellent, especially since I basically associated the mechanism with earthworms as well. However, after a quick verification it looks like "inchworm **drive**" is specific to RedPower, whereas the generic term is just "inchworm". I'll accept your answer of course, but could you reverify and edit if necessary?

Comment: @TheTerribleSwiftTomato I noticed that too, but my reasoning went like: "RedPower doesn't have a monopoly on a perfectly descriptive pair of words, and I know 'inchworm [somethingsomething]' is a real term. I'd call it a drive, and it acts like an inchworm, so 'inchworm drive', and lo! it's already called that in another Minecraft context. Inchworm drive it is." Edited to reflect that reasoning a bit better.

Comment: "[...]a monopoly on a perfectly descriptive pair of words,[...]". Heh, like *app store* ;)? By your description, your reasoning is sound, no further remarks :).

Comment: @TheTerribleSwiftTomato Fortunately we don't have trademark lawyers involved in mod wars! But yeah, I *believe* the term was created by the users of RedPower rather than Eloraam, so it's slightly different even so.